# TypeError: Db.connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Getting Error while creating a connection with MongoDB. Db.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db)
^**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var Db = mongo.Db;

exports.connect = function(mongoUri, callback) {
    console.log('Connecting to Mongo DB using URI: ' + mongoUri);
    Db.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error while connecting to Mongo DB: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
            console.log('Sucessfully connected to Mongo DB');
        }
        callback(db);
    });
}

exports.MongoConnector = function(db, collectionName) {
    this.db = db;
    this.collectionName = collectionName;
}
```

Comment: What is `Db`? It seems that it is not something you expected. Also please read about [mcve].

Comment: var mongo = require('mongodb');
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var Db = mongo.Db;

Comment: Well, you need to check the docs for the package. Pay attention to the recommended usage. `Db` is a class that is created internally by `MongoClient` and it has no static method `connect`. You need to instantiate a client, call `connect` on it.